# fatal error: libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory libxml/tree.h. In cyrus-imapd

Tags: c, debian

When I run the make of *cyrus-imapd-2.4.17-caldav-beta9* get the following error:

```
In file included from httpd.c:68:0:
httpd.h:48:25: fatal error: libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I'm trying to install this beta version that supports calendars.

I have installed libxml2-dev.

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

My operating system is Debian 7.

What am I forgetting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try including

```
`xml2-config --cflags`
```

and

```
`xml2-config --libs`
```

in your gcc args.  This will probably fix the issue.

Comment: I run "CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/libxml2 ./configure" and and solve the problem. Thank!.

Answer (score 0):

For some(in centos) who is not in this case, but encounter this error, the next may help (if in ubuntu, switch to 'apt install' ):

```
yum install -y libxml2-devel  libxml2
```